# How to make an atom like animation using CSS3 animations?

Tags: jquery, html, animation, css

I've being trying this since 3-4 days but am not able to get how do I make this animation, not even sure whether is possible to make one like this using only CSS3?

[image: Atom]

I tried using `animation-direction:alternate;` but I am not able to get this flow in a particular angle, able to animate it in a **square shape**.. but not the way atom animates, any idea how this can be accomplished using pure CSS3? if not is there any solution in jQuery?

Comment: This should  be closed on the same grounds the OP came up to close things like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500907/collapsible-panel-in-html-css (i personally think both are valid, but the OP clearly have double standards)

Comment: @gcb I don't mind closing it, if you compare the dates, I had asked this question when I was new to the website and was not aware of the rules :)

Comment: @gcb If you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13132864/1542290), you will find mine a lot better :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found [this](http://forrst.com/posts/CSS3_only_3D_Animated_Atom-4Dr) online.

It utilizes the `transform-style: preserve-3d` property and rotates the electrons on the x, y and z axis to achieve this 3D effect.

**HTML Structure**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="atom">
        <div class="orbit">
            <div class="path">
                <div class="electron"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orbit">
            <div class="path">
                <div class="electron"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orbit">
            <div class="path">
                <div class="electron"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orbit">
            <div class="path">
                <div class="electron"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="nucleus"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.orbit { 
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(80deg) rotateY(20deg);
}

#atom .orbit:nth-child(2) { 
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(80deg) rotateY(70deg)
}
#atom .orbit:nth-child(3) { 
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(80deg) rotateY(-20deg)
}
#atom .orbit:nth-child(4) { 
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(80deg) rotateY(-50deg)
}

.path { 
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-animation-name: pathRotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
}

.electron { 
    -webkit-animation-name: electronFix; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;  
}

@-webkit-keyframes pathRotate { 
    from { 
       -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
    } to { 
       -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg); 
    } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes electronFix { 
    from { 
       -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg); 
    } to { 
       -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(-360deg); 
    } 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgreater/kfgVr/)

[Blog Post](http://forrst.com/posts/CSS3_only_3D_Animated_Atom-4Dr)

Comment: its really awesome, but i dont understand one thing, if i can directly use the atom gif image, why would i go for css, where i have to write so much code.. :(

Comment: @RahulR. it's just fun to know what css alone can do, obviously you can use gif, which is even, better, no cross browser issues nothing but, than too I wanted a css solution ;)

Answer (score 7):

Definitely possible with CSS. I put an extremely basic together as a proof of concept before noticing @prashanth's post. The one he found is waaay cooler, but here's mine anyway...super bare-bones but a little fiddling and it'd look pretty good.

http://jsfiddle.net/BZFJ8/2/

Comment: agree that your's is quiet smart, but I don't have any Idea to float that ball from back to front, but a nice example +1

Comment: Manipulating the Z value in the translate3d property in the keyframe animation would let you change the electrons' relative position front-to-back, and adding a scale() value to the keyframes would let you change their size as they appear to move front to back.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one also looks like what you asked for but they said it is for Safari only animation as of Chrome 9

http://bgre.at/demo/CSS3-atom/index.html

You might find a solution with Jquery if you care about browser compatibly.