# How to create a radial menu in CSS?

Tags: css, tooltip, css-shapes

How do I create a menu which looks like so:

[image: Tooltip Image]

[Link to PSD](http://dribbble.com/shots/732391-Tooltip-PSD)

I don't want to use the PSD images. I would prefer using icons from some package like [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) and have the backgrounds/css generated in CSS.

A version of the menu that is using the PSD to to generate images of the tooltip and then using it can be found [here](http://theearlcarlson.com/experiments/amTooltip/).

Comment: That is a beautiful tooltip from a designer who clearly hates front end developers.

Comment: Tip: That’s a pie menu, not a tooltip.

Comment: Or a “radial menu.” Definitely not a “tooltip” though. Tooltips only ever show on hover, and cannot be interacted with. (They describe a tool; they are not a tool.)

Comment: There is also similar project on github http://nikesh.github.io/Pie-Menu/ by Nikesh Hayaran

Comment: The last link to an example of a menu made out of a PSD is broken, and, unfortunately, there is no meaningful version of that page saved by the Internet Archive’s [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org).

Answer (score 986, accepted):

*Almost 3 years later, I finally made the time to revisit this and post an improved version. You can still view the original answer at the end for reference.*

*While SVG may be the better choice, especially today, my goal with this was to keep it just HTML and CSS, no JS, no SVG, no images (other than the background on the root element).*

## ***[2015 demo](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/aOWeLa?editors=010)***

#### Screenshots

Chrome 43:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Firefox 38:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

IE 11:

[image: IE screenshot]

#### Code

The HTML is pretty simple. I'm using the checkbox hack to reveal/ hide the menu.

```
<input type='checkbox' id='t'/>
<label for='t'>✰</label>
<ul>
    <li><a href='#'>☀</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>☃</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>☁</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm using Sass to keep this logical and make it easier to change things if needed. Heavily commented.

```
$d: 2em; // diameter of central round button
$r: 16em; // radius of menu
$n: 3; // must match number of list items in DOM
$exp: 3em; // menu item height
$tip: .75em; // dimension of tip on middle menu item
$w: .5em; // width of ends
$cover-dim: 2*($r - $exp); // dimension of the link cover
$angle: 15deg; // angle for a menu item
$skew-angle: 90deg - $angle; // how much to skew a menu item to $angle
$scale-factor: cos($skew-angle); // correction factor - see vimeo.com/98137613 from min 15
$off-angle: .125deg; // offset angle so we have a little space between menu items

// don't show the actual checkbox
input {
  transform: translate(-100vw); // move offscreen
  visibility: hidden; // avoid paint
}

// change state of menu to revealed on checking the checkbox
input:checked ~ ul {
    transform: scale(1); 
    opacity: .999;
    // ease out back from easings.net/#easeOutBack
    transition: .5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

// position everything absolutely such that their left bottom corner 
// is in the middle of the screen
label, ul, li {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; bottom: 50%;
}

// visual candy styles
label, a {
    color: #858596;
    font: 700 1em/ #{$d} sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #6c6f7e;
    cursor: pointer;
}

label {
    z-index: 2; // place it above the menu which has z-index: 1
    margin: -$d/2; // position correction such that it's right in the middle
    width: $d; height: $d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px white, 
                0 .125em .25em #876366, 
                0 .125em .5em #876366;
    background: radial-gradient(#d4c7c5, #e5e1dd);
}

ul {
    z-index: 1;
    margin: -$r + $exp + 1.5*$d 0; // position correction
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    transform-origin: 50% (-$r + $exp);
    transform: scale(.001); // initial state: scaled down to invisible
    will-change: transform; // better perf on transitioning transform
    opacity: .001; // initial state: transparent
    filter: drop-shadow(0 .125em .25em #847c77) 
            drop-shadow(0 .125em .5em #847c77);
    // ease in back, also from easings.net
    transition: .5s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045);

    // menu ends
    &:before, &:after {
        position: absolute;
        margin: -$exp (-$w/2);
        width: $w; height: $exp;
        transform-origin: 50% 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(#ddd, #c9c4bf);
        content: '';
    }

    &:before {
        border-radius: $w 0 0 $w;
        transform: rotate(-.5*$n*$angle) 
                   translate(-$w/2, -$r + $exp);
        box-shadow: inset 1px 0 1px #eee;
    }
    &:after {
        border-radius: 0 $w $w 0;
        transform: rotate(.5*$n*$angle) 
            translate($w/2, -$r + $exp);
        box-shadow: inset -1px 0 1px #eee;
    }
}

li {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: $r; height: $r;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;

    @for $i from 0 to $n {
        &:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) {
            $curr-angle: $i*$angle + 
                ($i + .5)*$off-angle - 
                .5*$n*($angle + $off-angle);

            // make each list item a rhombus rotated around its bottom left corner
            // see explanation from minute 33:10 youtube.com/watch?v=ehjoh_MmE9A
            transform: rotate($curr-angle)
                       skewY(-$skew-angle) 
                       scaleX($scale-factor);

            // add tip for the item n the middle, just a rotated square
            @if $i == ($n - 1)/2 {
                a:after {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: $exp; left: 50%;
                    margin: -$tip/2;
                    width: $tip; height: $tip;
                    transform: rotate(45deg);
                    box-shadow: 
                        inset -1px -1px 1px #eee;
                    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, 
                        #bbb, #c9c4bf 50%);
                    content: '';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    a, &:before {
        margin: 0 (-$r);
        width: 2*$r; height: 2*$r;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    &:before, &:after {
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 50%;
        // undo distorting transforms from menu item (parent li)
        transform: scaleX(1/$scale-factor) 
                   skewY($skew-angle);
        content: '';
    }

    // actual background of the arched menu items
    &:before {
        box-shadow: 
            inset 0 0 1px 1px #fff, 
            inset 0 0 $exp #ebe7e2, 
            inset 0 0 1px ($exp - .0625em) #c9c4bf, 
            inset 0 0 0 $exp #dcdcdc;
    }

    // cover to prevent click action in between the star and menu items
    &:after {
        top: 100%; left: 0;
        margin: -$cover-dim/2;
        width: $cover-dim; height: $cover-dim;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
}

a {
    display: block;
    // undo distorting transforms from menu item and rotate into right position
    transform: scaleX(1/$scale-factor) 
               skewY($skew-angle) 
               rotate($angle/2);
    line-height: $exp;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/AeFfmwL.jpg);
}

input {
  /* move offscreen */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100vw);
      -ms-transform: translate(-100vw);
          transform: translate(-100vw);
  /* avoid paint */
  visibility: hidden;
}

input:checked ~ ul {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  opacity: .999;
  /* ease out back from easings.net */
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
          transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

label, ul, li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
}

label, a {
  color: #858596;
  font: 700 1em/ 2em sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #6c6f7e;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  z-index: 2;
  margin: -1em;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px white,  0 .125em .25em #876366,  0 .125em .5em #876366;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#d4c7c5, #e5e1dd);
  background: radial-gradient(#d4c7c5, #e5e1dd);
}

ul {
  z-index: 1;
  margin: -10em 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% -13em;
      -ms-transform-origin: 50% -13em;
          transform-origin: 50% -13em;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.001);
      -ms-transform: scale(0.001);
          transform: scale(0.001);
  /* for improved perf on transitioning transform
   * https://twitter.com/paul_irish/status/608492121734193152
   */
  will-change: transform;
  opacity: .001;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0.125em 0.25em #847c77);
          filter: drop-shadow(0 0.125em 0.25em #847c77);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045);
          transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045);
}
ul:before, ul:after {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -3em -0.25em;
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 3em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
          transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ddd, #c9c4bf);
  background: linear-gradient(#ddd, #c9c4bf);
  content: '';
}
ul:before {
  border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-22.5deg) translate(-0.25em, -13em);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-22.5deg) translate(-0.25em, -13em);
          transform: rotate(-22.5deg) translate(-0.25em, -13em);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0 1px #eee;
}
ul:after {
  border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg) translate(0.25em, -13em);
      -ms-transform: rotate(22.5deg) translate(0.25em, -13em);
          transform: rotate(22.5deg) translate(0.25em, -13em);
  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 1px #eee;
}

li {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 16em;
  height: 16em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
          transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-22.625deg) skewY(-75deg) scaleX(0.25882);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-22.625deg) skewY(-75deg) scaleX(0.25882);
          transform: rotate(-22.625deg) skewY(-75deg) scaleX(0.25882);
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-7.5deg) skewY(-75deg) scaleX(0.25882);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-7.5deg) skewY(-75deg) scaleX(0.25882);
          transform: rotate(-7.5deg) skewY(-75deg) scaleX(0.25882);
}
li:nth-child(2) a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -0.375em;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 1px #eee;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #bbb, #c9c4bf 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #bbb, #c9c4bf 50%);
  content: '';
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(7.625deg) skewY(-75deg) scaleX(0.25882);
      -ms-transform: rotate(7.625deg) skewY(-75deg) scaleX(0.25882);
          transform: rotate(7.625deg) skewY(-75deg) scaleX(0.25882);
}
li a, li:before {
  margin: 0 -16em;
  width: 32em;
  height: 32em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
li:before, li:after {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(3.8637) skewY(75deg);
      -ms-transform: scaleX(3.8637) skewY(75deg);
          transform: scaleX(3.8637) skewY(75deg);
  content: '';
}
li:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #fff, inset 0 0 3em #ebe7e2, inset 0 0 1px 2.9375em #c9c4bf, inset 0 0 0 3em #dcdcdc;
}
li:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin: -13em;
  width: 26em;
  height: 26em;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

a {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(3.8637) skewY(75deg) rotate(7.5deg);
      -ms-transform: scaleX(3.8637) skewY(75deg) rotate(7.5deg);
          transform: scaleX(3.8637) skewY(75deg) rotate(7.5deg);
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='t'/>
<label for='t'>✰</label>
<ul>
 <li><a href='#'>☀</a></li>
 <li><a href='#'>☃</a></li>
 <li><a href='#'>☁</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

### Original answer

My attempt at doing something of the kind with pure CSS:

## [*demo*](http://dabblet.com/gist/3979221/cb69c5e8ccf0745fff2c94b47b27b108931f1a15)

(click the star)

Works in Chrome, Firefox (a bit weirdish blur effect on hover), Opera (ends look smaller) & Safari (ends look smaller).

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body {
 overflow: hidden;
}
/* generic styles for button & circular menu */
.ctrl {
 position: absolute;
 top: 70%; left: 50%;
 font: 1.5em/1.13 Verdana, sans-serif;
 transition: .5s;
}
/* generic link styles */
a.ctrl, .ctrl a {
 display: block;
 opacity: .56;
 background: #c9c9c9;
 color: #7a8092;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px dimgrey;
}
a.ctrl:hover, .ctrl a:hover, a.ctrl:focus, .ctrl a:focus { opacity: 1; }
a.ctrl:focus, .ctrl a:focus { outline: none; }
.button {
 z-index: 2;
 margin: -.625em;
 width: 1.25em; height: 1.25em;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px white;
}
/* circular menu */
.tip {
 z-index: 1;
 /**outline: dotted 1px white;/**/
 margin: -5em;
 width: 10em; height: 10em;
 transform: scale(.001);
 list-style: none;
 opacity: 0;
}
/* the ends of the menu */
.tip:before, .tip:after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 34.3%;
 width: .5em; height: 14%;
 opacity: .56;
 background: #c9c9c9;
 content: '';
}
.tip:before {
 left: 5.4%;
 border-radius: .25em 0 0 .25em;
 box-shadow: -1px 0 1px dimgrey, inset 1px 0 1px white, inset -1px 0 1px grey, 
    inset 0 1px 1px white, inset 0 -1px 1px white;
 transform: rotate(-75deg);
}
.tip:after {
 right: 5.4%;
 border-radius: 0 .25em .25em 0;
 box-shadow: 1px 0 1px dimgrey, inset -1px 0 1px white, inset 1px 0 1px grey,
    inset 0 1px 1px white, inset 0 -1px 1px white;
 transform: rotate(75deg);
}
/* make the menu appear on click */
.button:focus + .tip {
 transform: scale(1);
 opacity: 1;
}
/* slices of the circular menu */
.slice {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 /**outline: dotted 1px yellow;/**/
 width: 50%; height: 50%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
/* 
 * rotate each slice at the right angle = (A/2)° + (k - (n+1)/2)*A°
 * where A is the angle of 1 slice (30° in this case)
 * k is the number of the slice (in {1,2,3,4,5} here)
 * and n is the number of slices (5 in this case)
 * formula works for odd number of slices (n odd)
 * for even number of slices (n even) the rotation angle is (k - n/2)*A°
 * 
 * after rotating, skew on Y by 90°-A°; here A° = the angle for 1 slice = 30° 
 */
.slice:first-child { transform: rotate(-45deg) skewY(60deg); }
.slice:nth-child(2) { transform: rotate(-15deg) skewY(60deg); }
.slice:nth-child(3) { transform: rotate(15deg) skewY(60deg); }
.slice:nth-child(4) { transform: rotate(45deg) skewY(60deg); }
.slice:last-child { transform: rotate(75deg) skewY(60deg); }
/* covers for the inner part of the links so there's no hover trigger between
   star button & menu links; give them a red background to see them */
.slice:after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 32%; left: 32%;
 width: 136%; height: 136%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 /* "unskew" = skew by minus the same angle by which parent was skewed */
 transform: skewY(-60deg);
 content: '';
}
/* menu links */
.slice a {
 width: 200%; height: 200%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px dimgrey, inset 0 0 4px white;
 /* "unskew" & rotate by -A°/2 */
 transform: skewY(-60deg) rotate(-15deg);
 background: /* lateral separators */
   linear-gradient(75deg, 
  transparent 50%, grey 50%, transparent 54%) no-repeat 36.5% 0,
   linear-gradient(-75deg, 
  transparent 50%, grey 50%, transparent 54%) no-repeat 63.5% 0,
  /* make sure inner part is transparent */
  radial-gradient(rgba(127,127,127,0) 49%, 
     rgba(255,255,255,.7) 51%, #c9c9c9 52%);
 background-size: 15% 15%, 15% 15%, cover;
 line-height: 1.4;
}
/* arrow for middle link */
.slice:nth-child(3) a:after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 13%; left: 50%;
 margin: -.25em;
 width: .5em; height: .5em;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px white;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #c9c9c9 50%, transparent 50%);
 content: '';
}
```

```html
<a class='button ctrl' href='#' tabindex='1'>★</a>
<ul class='tip ctrl'>
 <li class='slice'><a href='#'>✦</a></li>
 <li class='slice'><a href='#'>✿</a></li>
 <li class='slice'><a href='#'>✵</a></li>
 <li class='slice'><a href='#'>✪</a></li>
 <li class='slice'><a href='#'>☀</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: and who said CSS isn't programming? :D

Comment: Very nice! I would put the menu a bit closer to the center point. I am  a bit lazy when it comes to moving the mouse cursor around my screen :)

Comment: @lucassp [All these people](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196260/does-a-programming-language-have-to-be-compiled-to-be-considered-a-programming-l?noredirect=1#comment380294_196260)

Comment: FWIW, this approach breaks in latest Chrome if you use Tab to cycle through the elements.

Comment: From what I can tell this also works in IE10 though maybe not fully, I haven't tested it in Chrome yet to see how it should work.

Comment: @iGanja 1. I don't remember, but the idea is really simple and there are about 6 hours between the question and my answer and I usually sleep at the hour this was asked... so probably it didn't take me long. 2. No, I don't have a real job and I actually have nothing in common with web development except demos like these. As for a "real life", I believe everyone has a "real life" as long as they're breathing on their own.

Comment: @Superpig True. This version shouldn't have that problem anymore http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/jfqtv

Comment: @Ana When I click on the background with the mouse, then I click on the [tab] button : [Hell Breaks](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4552000/Selection_119.png "Hell Breaks")

Comment: can you write a few words explaining how it works? i m surprised at how css can have state (the click on the .button class anchor changes the state of the menu, but i m unable to work out where/how this info is stored in the css).

Comment: @Chii See http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/ - what I have used here is *"the `:focus` way"*. It's a pretty old method actually, I first saw it used by Stu Nicholls in his experiments on http://www.cssplay.co.uk/ quite a few years ago. In the CSS above, it's the `.button:focus + .tip` that does the trick.

Comment: No offense intended Ana; I should have read your about.me profile before my comment. I wish I had your luxury of time; would make "playing with things" easier and more fun for sure. :)  Still, great job with this; quite ingenious.

Comment: @Ana and @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI: to prevent tabbing to those links altogether you can simply give them a [negative tabindex](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#negative-tabindex) (`tabindex="-1"`). Great solution, it's a shame you can't favourite answers as well as questions!

Comment: Remember that the css transform property is not supported in IE 9, Safari and Chrome. Use -ms-transform and -webkit-transform instead (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)

Comment: @PascalKlein Have you bothered read the support info in the answer or to check the demo in these browsers? It works in Chrome and Safari because the demo uses `-prefix-free` (see http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/ ). It does not work in IE9, but that's not because of the transform. It's because of the gradients.I don't see the point of including prefixes in the code posted here (even though I always use `-prefix-free` or include all the prefixes in the actual demo), it would only make things more difficult to understand.

Comment: @Ana Thanks for your answer. Now I know what you meant by "Relevant CSS (no prefixes)". I actually visited both demos: the one in your answer and the one in your comment. But I never heared about prefixfree.js, so I could not figure out, why your demo actually worked in chrome und my copy of your code did. Thanks for the link, I guess I will use prefixfree.js in the future as well.

Comment: Does anyone else get some keyup javascript errors in the console ?

Comment: Why didn't you scale the tip all the way down to `0` (and you scaled to `.001`)?

Comment: @gion_13 Scaling to `.5` is `2` times smaller. Scaling to `0` is how many times smaller? I'd rather not introduce infinities in the CSS.

Comment: @Ana no hover effect on the newest version?

Comment: This raises the question, can or should you be able to "favourite" an answer?

Answer (score 61):

Ana's response is kick ass!  That's some serious CSS-fu.

My solution may not be quite what you are hoping for, but it's another possible solution. I'm working on a compass interface right now that has a similar style of arc shaped buttons.  I decided to develop it using [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) and SVG.

I created an arc shape in Illustrator, exported the SVG for it, grabbed the path definition for the arc from the exported SVG file, and used Raphael to build my interface with it.

### [Here's a JSFiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/elliotlarson/jUTFm/).

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var arc = {
    fill: '#333',
    stroke: '#333',
    path: 'M53.286,44.333L69.081,7.904C48.084-1.199,23.615-2.294,0.648,6.78l14.59,36.928C28.008,38.662,41.612,39.27,53.286,44.333z'
};

var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("notepad"), 500, 500);

var arcDegrees = 45;
var centerX = 210;
var centerY = 210;
var compassRadius = 68;
var currentlyActive = 45;
var directions = [
    {label:'N', degrees:0, rotatedDegrees:270}, 
    {label:'NE', degrees:45, rotatedDegrees:315}, 
    {label:'E', degrees:90, rotatedDegrees:0}, 
    {label:'SE', degrees:135, rotatedDegrees:45}, 
    {label:'S', degrees:180, rotatedDegrees:90}, 
    {label:'SW', degrees:225, rotatedDegrees:135}, 
    {label:'W', degrees:270, rotatedDegrees:180}, 
    {label:'NW', degrees:315, rotatedDegrees:225}
];

function arcClicked()
{
    var label = $(this).data('direction-label');
    $("#activeArc").attr('id', null);
    $(this).attr('id', 'activeArc');
}

for (i = 0; i < 360; i += arcDegrees) {
    var direction = _.find(directions, function(d) { return d.rotatedDegrees == i; });
    var radians = i * (Math.PI / 180);
    var x = centerX + Math.cos(radians) * compassRadius;
    var y = centerY + Math.sin(radians) * compassRadius;
        
    var newArc = paper.path(arc.path);
    // newArc.translate(x, y);
    // newArc.rotate(i + 89);
    newArc.transform('T' + x + ',' + y + 'r' + (i + 89));
    
    if (direction.degrees == currentlyActive) {
        $(newArc.node).attr('id', 'activeArc');
    }
        
    $(newArc.node)
        .attr('class', 'arc')
        .data('direction-label', direction.label)
        .on('click', arcClicked);
}
```

Here's the related CSS:

```
#notepad {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.arc {
    fill: #999;
    stroke: #888;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.arc:hover {
    fill: #777;
    stroke: #666;
}

#activeArc {
    fill: #F18B21 !important;
    stroke: #b86a19 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Another very good way would be to use JavaScript for the positioning.

[**DEMO + TUTORIAL on making an animated radial menu**](http://creative-punch.net/2014/02/making-animated-radial-menu-css3-javascript/)

A pro to this method is that you can use any number of elements and it will keep positioning them radially, without having to change any of your CSS.

The JavaScript in question is:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');

for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
  items[i].style.left = (50 - 35*Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";

  items[i].style.top = (50 + 35*Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
}

document.querySelector('.menu-button').onclick = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); document.querySelector('.circle').classList.toggle('open');
}
```

Comment: simple and easy to understand. also very flexible as you can add new item without adjusting the js code. well done!

Comment: If we have to change the position of the menu-button then how we should go about it?? Can you please explain me what is this 50 and 35 mean?

Comment: Much more maintainable example. The css only version would be almost impossible to extend or debug