# how to create curve responsive menu in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

i wanna create curve menu using html and css.not svg!
my menu is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKnRx.png)

i search alot but no solution was found.i also saw    [How to make curve style menu in css3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547878/how-to-make-curve-style-menu-in-css3.but) its not what i need
.this menu should be responsive.
when i use svg .i should create svg in different size for every resolution.its too hard wanna another way.is there any help?

Comment: Please try http://custom.simplemachines.org/mods/index.php?mod=4040

Comment: hey , you can try this sample - [wave menu](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/ICHKq)

Comment: Is this a responsive design or for a fixed size? A menu with complex graphic can not be responsive if you don't make menu items dynamic against the graphical resize of menu. It would be very complex.

Comment: it is responsive.in my opinion,always  there is a soulution.is not?you have not any solution?