# Retreiving coordinates of a click inside a div for modern browsers?

Tags: javascript

For modern browsers (IE 10+, FF, Safari, Chrome):  It looks like you would have to use the facade pattern to build a consistent interface and do a lot of fiddling using this info.

I'm looking for a simple modern way to determine the x, y coordinates of where a user clicked in a div and use those coordinates to position a pie menu as determined in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992537/implementing-a-single-pie-menu-for-multiple-elements).

No libraries unless used to show concept.

**Reference**

[What is the difference between screenX/Y, clientX/Y and pageX/Y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073505/what-is-the-difference-between-screenx-y-clientx-y-and-pagex-y)

Here is a [google hit](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mouseclickeventcoordinates.htm) that shows 3 different event properties

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
element.onclick = function(e) {
  var x = e.pageX - element.offsetLeft // the absolute x position
                                       // minus the element's absolute x position
  var y = e.pageY - element.offsetTop
  alert('x : ' + x + ', y : ' + y)
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tP3jT/)

Answer (score 1):

the following will give you the coordinates for any div clicked in the page; for a specific div replace 'div' with '#yourDivId'

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $('div').click(function(e){
       var x = e.pageX; 
       var y = e.pageY;
       alert(...);
   });
});
```