# How to implement half-circle menu (sub item) with CSS and JavaScript on mobile web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, geometry, submenu

I want to use a half-circle menu when I surf the mobile web with my right hand. Can somebody teach me how to implement half-circle menu (sub item) with CSS and JavaScript on mobile web? I have tried it with CSS `transform:rotate` and `border-radius`, but it could not be worked successfully.

> [image]
>
> There is a half-circle menu button, this button can open and close menu. When I click the menu button, the main-level will be popped up. Then I click "Main 1", the sub-level (Sub 1-1, Sub 1-2, Sub 1-3) will be popped up.

> [image]
>
> As just mentioned, When I click "Main 6", the sub-level (Sub 6-1, Sub 6-2, Sub 6-3) will be popped up.

Here is the architecture of the menu:

```
Menu
   Main 1
      Sub 1-1
      Sub 1-2
      Sub 1-3
   Main 2
      Sub 2-1
      Sub 2-2
      Sub 2-3
   Main 3
      Sub 3-1
      Sub 3-2
      Sub 3-3
   Main 4
      Sub 4-1
      Sub 4-2
      Sub 4-3
   Main 5
      Sub 5-1
      Sub 5-2
      Sub 5-3
   Main 6
      Sub 6-1
      Sub 6-2
      Sub 6-3
```

Comment: There is a detailed example of half circle menu in tympanus.net . [> Building a Circular Navigation with CSS Transforms](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/) It explains step by step accompanied with images how to build the effect.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132864/creating-a-radial-menu-in-css

Answer (score 46):

You could do this with **SVG**. When you click on `first-ring` buttons or (Main 1, Main 2...) it will update text of `second-ring` buttons or (Sub 1 1, Sub 2 1...), and this is just for demo purpose. You can use **js** to change links inside `<a xlink:href=""></a>` instead of just text.

```js
var firstRing = $('.first-ring');
var secondRing = $('.second-ring');
var siblings = firstRing.siblings('.second-ring');
var open = $('#open');

open.click(function() {
  firstRing.toggleClass('show');

  if (!firstRing.hasClass('show')) {
    siblings.removeClass('show');
  }
});

firstRing.children('g').click(function() {
  var data = $(this).data('url');
  siblings.addClass('show');

  secondRing.children('g').children('a').children('text').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().split(' ');
    $(this).text(text[0] + ' ' + data + ' ' + text[2]);
  });
});
```

```css
svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 12px;
}

g {
  fill: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}

text {
  fill: white;
}

g:not(.first-ring):not(.second-ring):hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.first-ring, .second-ring {
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.main      {fill: #2B2B2B;}
.one       {fill: #2B2B2B;}
.two       {fill: #373737;}
.three     {fill: #444444;}
.four      {fill: #515151;}
.five      {fill: #5E5E5E;}
.six       {fill: #6A6A6A;}
.sub-one   {fill: #777777;}
.sub-two   {fill: #848484;}
.sub-three {fill: #909090;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<svg width="400px" height="400px">
  <!-- This is First ring or Menu part-->
  <g id="open">
    <path class="main" d="M395.545,200.03l-0.08-0.12l-0.05,0.12l-22.44,54.17c-7.12-2.97-13.54-7.311-18.909-12.69
  c-5.41-5.41-9.771-11.87-12.75-19.05c-2.86-6.91-4.44-14.49-4.44-22.43c0-7.91,1.56-15.45,4.4-22.33
  c2.96-7.19,7.31-13.66,12.71-19.07c5.42-5.45,11.899-9.83,19.109-12.82L395.545,200.03z" />
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 351.7607 206.0303)" class="st1 st3">MENU</text>
  </g>

  <!-- This is second-ring -->
  <g class="first-ring">
    <g data-url="1">
      <path class="one" d="M373.095,145.81c-7.21,2.99-13.689,7.37-19.109,12.82l-50.94-50.9c12.06-12.08,26.47-21.82,42.5-28.46
  L373.095,145.81z" />
      <text transform="matrix(0.5061 0.8625 -0.8625 0.5061 332.1963 107.73)" class="st1 st3">Main 1</text>
    </g>
    <g data-url="2">
      <path class="two" d="M353.985,158.63c-5.4,5.41-9.75,11.88-12.71,19.07l-66.58-27.45c6.609-16.02,16.31-30.44,28.35-42.52
  L353.985,158.63z" />
      <text transform="matrix(0.8283 0.5603 -0.5603 0.8283 295.585 136.9624)" class="st1 st3">Main 2</text>
    </g>
    <g data-url="3">
      <path class="three" d="M341.275,177.7c-2.841,6.88-4.4,14.42-4.4,22.33h-72c0-17.63,3.49-34.44,9.82-49.78L341.275,177.7z" />
      <text transform="matrix(0.9946 0.1039 -0.1039 0.9946 283.0908 183.2314)" class="st1 st3">Main 3</text>
    </g>
    <g data-url="4">
      <path class="four" d="M341.315,222.46l-66.53,27.57c-6.391-15.4-9.91-32.29-9.91-50h72
  C336.875,207.97,338.455,215.55,341.315,222.46z" />
      <text transform="matrix(0.9891 -0.1475 0.1475 0.9891 283.0898 225.0303)" class="st1 st3">Main4</text>
    </g>
    <g data-url="5">
      <path class="five" d="M354.065,241.51l-50.841,51c-12.08-12.06-21.8-26.46-28.439-42.479l66.53-27.57
  C344.295,229.64,348.655,236.1,354.065,241.51z" />
      <text transform="matrix(0.8627 -0.5057 0.5057 0.8627 299.6768 268.6953)" class="st1 st3">Main 5</text>
    </g>
    <g data-url="6">
      <path class="six" d="M372.975,254.2l-27.56,66.53c-15.89-6.601-30.2-16.25-42.19-28.221l50.841-51
  C359.435,246.89,365.854,251.23,372.975,254.2z" />
      <text transform="matrix(0.6338 -0.7735 0.7735 0.6338 332.1963 300.0664)" class="st1 st3">Main 6</text>
    </g>
  </g>

  <!-- This is third-ring or sub part -->
  <g class="second-ring">
    <g>
      <a xlink:href="">
        <path class="sub-one" d="M345.545,79.27c-16.03,6.64-30.44,16.38-42.5,28.46c-12.04,12.08-21.74,26.5-28.35,42.52l-54.061-22.3
  c9.59-23.18,23.66-44.03,41.141-61.47c17.46-17.42,38.319-31.45,61.5-40.99L345.545,79.27z" />
        <text transform="matrix(0.7099 0.7043 -0.7043 0.7099 263.1514 75.9663)" class="st1 st3">Sub 1 1</text>
      </a>
    </g>

    <g>
      <a xlink:href="">
        <path class="sub-two" d="M274.785,250.03l-54.02,22.399c-9.271-22.29-14.391-46.75-14.391-72.4c0-25.53,5.07-49.87,14.26-72.08
  l54.061,22.3c-6.33,15.34-9.82,32.15-9.82,49.78C264.875,217.74,268.395,234.63,274.785,250.03z" />
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 213.585 200.1899)" class="st1 st3">Sub 1 2</text>
      </a>
    </g>

    <g>
      <a xlink:href="">
        <path class="sub-three" d="M345.415,320.73l-22.28,53.779c-23.01-9.49-43.74-23.41-61.109-40.68c-17.51-17.41-31.631-38.24-41.26-61.4
  l54.02-22.399c6.64,16.02,16.359,30.42,28.439,42.479C315.215,304.48,329.525,314.13,345.415,320.73z" />
        <text transform="matrix(0.7305 -0.6829 0.6829 0.7305 266.9395 328.9912)" class="st1 st3">Sub 1 3</text>
      </a>
    </g>

  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 9):

[image]

No SVG, just plain css.

Basically,

- just turn rectangles over the same corner with increasing angles. Like a paper fan.
- Put the whole thing at the outermost level into a circle (`border-radius:r px;overflow: hidden`).
- Repeat for any further, outer rings.
- Add another outer `overflow:hidden` wrapper, if the enlarged last menu (‚menu 5‘) bothers you...
- Javascript is only needed, as soon as you deal with clicks and want to toggle outer rings visibility for sub-options...

➪ **http://codepen.io/fnocke/pen/Vazobq?editors=0100**

This is simplified stylus syntax (similar to less, sass), see codepen➝‘view compiled’ for full css:

```
li
  position absolute
  top 50%
  display block
  transform-origin top right
  overflow hidden
  width r
  height r

li:nth-of-type(1)
  transform: rotate(60deg)
  background #000
li:nth-of-type(2)
  transform: rotate(40deg)
  background #222
..
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use an SVG library. Trying to make it with basic HTML elements and jQuery is probably possible using image maps, but wrapping it around jQuery will make you want to kill yourself.

I recommend [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) since it not only handles presentation part (looks, animations) but also data with which you'll feed it.

Comment: _"jQuery will make you want to kill yourself"_ Quote of the day!! Hard to debug, huge overhead, etc. it's not worth it!