# Designing using HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: html, css, web

I need pointers to how to proceed to design the attached image.I have created a circular div but not able to proceed to add content across the border.

Any help would be great.Thanks.[image]

Comment: You could use a sprite for the icons and place them with `:before` on the grey areas. But first: can we see your `CSS` and `HTML`, please?

Comment: There is an answer that has 800 votes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13137862/1926369 and that can help you

Comment: A simple Google search yielded this http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/ just extract the technique and modify to your needs!