# Identifying an Unknown Web Chart Component

Tags: html, charts, components

[image: What's this chart component called? I want to use it for my App]

I have come across a component in a few web applications; however, the html doesn't identify the component's name. Nor have I found it online. Anyone know what this component type is or where it comes from?

Comment: This comment is probably entirely not correct; however, it might lead you in the right direction. The .Net Framework has a series of tools that can be purchased and are meant for ASP .Net applications: DevExpress tools. They call these "[radial menus](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsRibbonRadialMenuMembersTopicAll)". A near equivalent in JavaScript (jQuery) is the [circle pop up](http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/circle%20menu/) (check out the pie menu).

Comment: Can you link us to a web application that uses the component? Also check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132864/creating-a-radial-menu-in-css), it might be of help to you. Though, I am big fan of not re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I've seen this component in screenshots at http://www.crimsonhexagon.com/, and Sprinklr.com system uses it as charts of sort of Word Topics / Word clouds

Comment: It's more of a Chart than a Radial Menu. I need to to represent sort of a categorized Word Cloud

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of frameworks that employ pre-packaged versions of the example image you have posted in your question, all the way from proprietary UI frameworks, such as [DevExpress](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument14628) for the .Net Framework, to [solutions](http://creative-punch.net/2014/02/making-animated-radial-menu-css3-javascript/) implemented in a more open-source-friendly manner, i.e. you can see the code.

Without knowing the URL of the web application to which you are refering (e.g. `.aspx`, etc), it is difficult to know what framework the web app. is employing.

### Menu

These menu types are generally called "radial menus" and a good [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=radial%20menu%20website) would yield lots of great results. Sometimes knowing the terminology is all you need.

Some people have provided some very [complex solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132864/creating-a-radial-menu-in-css) to getting the type of behaviour you are looking for; however, in my opinion, re-inventing the wheel is a waste of time and money (it's great for hobbying around, though, certainly). The amount of time tooling around is perhaps better spent learning a little more about something else that will save you time in the future (and make your solutions re-implementable).

### Diagram

Again, these guys are using stuff designed by people who are really passionate about web visual design. [GitHub](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) has a number of open source projects available for examination. For the record, I Googled: "[circular word occurrence chart](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=circular%20word%20occurrence%20chart)". [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423) is a directly relevant example from that repository mentioned, above.

The substance of my answer? A lot of these things you are seeing are employing more than just HTML and CSS to make their applications display information in such interesting ways.