# How to make a parfect folding system?

Tags: html

I am trying to make a folding system. I want to make it like this code. But it didn't work perfectly. I wish that when f1 folded then f2 will unfold. Or f2 folded then f1 unfold. But it did not work.

```
<div class="nfooter" style="text-aling: left;">
<table width="100%">
<td width="50%">
<a href="fold:;f1" onclick="location.href='fold:f2'">
a
</a>
</td>
<td width="50%">
<a href="fold:;f2" onclick="location.href='fold:f1'">
b
</a>
</td>
</table>
</div>
<div class="chat-up" id="f2">
a
</div>
<div class="chat-up" id="f3">
b
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collapsible Panel in HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500907/collapsible-panel-in-html-css)

Comment: What's a folding system?